# Piping from youtube-dl to jq in command substitution

Tags: bash, youtube-dl, jq

When I run

```
youtube-dl -j "$youtube_url" | jq
```

I get a nice json output. However, when I run

```
json=$(youtube-dl -j "$youtube_url" | jq)
```

then `jq` prints it's usage page and after that youtube-dl fails with a `broken pipe` error. The `json`-variable is empty.

I'm guessing that `jq` runs before `youtube-dl` and since there is no data on stdin then it terminates printing the usage instructions. When `jq` is no longer running then there is no pipe to write to so then `youtube-dl` fails. This is just a guess though. I do not really understand what is going on here. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964481/10765659):

> Just calling `jq` without a filter will throw errors if stdout isn't a terminal. […] Try `jq '.'`. […] Note that the filter is not really optional.

In your case:

```
json=$(youtube-dl -j "$youtube_url" | jq '.')
```

---

Side note:

In general when you run `foo | bar`, well written `foo` will wait if `bar` doesn't read fast enough; and well written `bar` will wait if `foo` doesn't write fast enough. It doesn't matter which one starts first.

We can argue if `jq` is "well written". Still your problem originated from its quirky behavior depending on stdout, not on stdin. Your hypothesis is false.